# Systemctl not found on Buster

Tags: systemd

I recently downloaded the Buster lite installation package and have the latest updates. I get systemctl not found. The systemd files it uses are present. Apt-get systemctl fails. I need to run commands such as systemctl daemon-restart. I have researched this and found 'get the latest OS' but I have the latest OS. How do I get systemctl ?

Comment: Pls add exact command *and* full error msg to your question

Answer (score 2):

There are two likely possibilities:

- `systemctl` is gone
- your shell cannot find it

To see if `systemctl` is still there, you can do `find / -name systemctl`. If it is there, try to execute it with the whole pathname (like `/bin/systemctl`).

If `find` does not find it, it is gone. Then you may try to copy `/bin/systemctl` from an image that has the same version of OS as your Pi, but there is no guarantee tat it will work. That depends on what other files are missing. I would try this only as part of the actions to backup data before re-imaging your system.

To see if `systemctl` is still there, you can do `find / -name systemctl`. If it is there, try to execute it with the whole pathname (like `/bin/systemctl`). If that works, then you must look at your `PATH` in your shell:

```
echo $PATH
```

The output should contain the directory where `systemctl` is

Example:

```
$ sudo find / -name systemctl 2> /dev/null
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl
/bin/systemctl
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
$
```

You seen here that `/bin/systemctl` exists and you see `/bin` in the `PATH`.  So, on my system, `systemctl` works.

Comment: There is at least one more possibility: the command was typed wrong. We know nothing and everything is guessing.

Comment: @ingo There may be even more possibilities. That is why I tried to include some basic problem determination in the answer, instead of just saying that the system is corrupt and tell to re-image.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is really this:

```
pi> systemctl
sh: systemctl: command not found
```

**And** the output of `echo $PATH` includes:

```
/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Then something went very wrong, most likely SD card corruption, the usual cause of which is not shutting the Pi down properly before killing the power/pulling the plug.

In any case, there is no point in you trying to repair this.  You will have to start again by re-imaging the card. If you did pull the plug arbitrarily, try not to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the "Buster lite" package does not ship with `systemd` installed by default. (Perhaps provide a link so we can confirm?)

You can install it just like any other package.

```sh
# Make sure package index is up to date
apt-get update
# Install
apt-get install -y systemd
```

You will probably have to enable some services and reboot before it becomes fully operational.  Alternatively, use a less "lite" image if you need the full system, not a stripped-down one.